# No Flutter module found

Tags: android, flutter-module

In my android studio, I've installed the flutter & Dart plugin. I can create a new flutter project. I want to create a flutter module in my android project. But the android studio is unable to show the option. How to resolve it?

[No Flutter Module option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRqKU.png)

[Flutter Project option is there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlgg0.png)

FLutter version - 2.18
Android studio - 2020.3.1 patch 4

Comment: I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Follow this - https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app/android/project-setup#create-a-flutter-module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create Flutter Module by Flutter cli.

https://docs.flutter.dev/reference/flutter-cli

Comment: I used it. But the flutter module isn't showing in android studio. I used ' flutter create -t module --org com.example modulename' , then set flutter module path in cmd and ''flutter build aar'. Still, it is not working.